# How do you run trigger("create") on content loaded with ajax?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a function that refreshes the content on a page after a form is filled out. It works but the jquery mobile elements are not formatted. Calling trigger() is not working because apparently it is getting called before the elements appear on the page. Here's the code:

```
function add_note() {
  var vid = $("#basic_note_vid_hidden").val(); 
  note = $("#basic_note_textarea").val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br />");
  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.pl",
    data: "action=add_note&vid=" + vid + "&note=" + note,
    error: function(res) {
             $.growl({title:"Update failed!", style: "error",message:"Are you connected to the Internet?", static:true, size: 'medium' })
           },  
    success: function(res) {
               $.growl({title:"Update successful", message:"Note added", duration:500, size: 'small' }); 
               $("#basic_note_close_button").click(); 
               $("#basic_note_textarea").val('');
               $("#notes .ui-content").load('ajax.pl?action=print_note_ajax&vid=' + vid).parent().trigger('create');
             },  
  }); 
}
```

The meat of the matter is the very last line of code. Is there a way to detect when the new content gets loaded into the page so I know when I can call the trigger() function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm obviously still learning basic jquery. Answer was in the docs for load():

```
           $("#notes .ui-content").load('ajax.pl?action=print_note_ajax&vid=' + vid, function() {
             $('#notes .ui-content').trigger('create');
           });
```